# Explanation of the sum of angles of a triangle equaling pi based on motion

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I read somewhere that Klein kind of formalized the study of geometry through motion. Is there an explanation of the sum of the angles of a triangle equaling pi based on translations and rotations? I think that it could start from this model : starting point, we move at a speed v in straight lines, we must use 2 rotations to come back to the initial point.

Comment: This is a good question. It will take me some time to get some graphics in order, but I will hopefully be able to answer in a few hours.

Comment: In geometry the word motion does no refer to _actual motion_ to which speed can be assigned. The word motion refers to congruence transformations in general. When such a transformation is a translation along a straight line the the word _motion_ is intuitive though.

Comment: I've been thinking about this question for 13 hours and I don't seem to be able to understand it. Let me ask two questions: Why do do you want to get back to the initial point? Why is it important that you do two rotations?

Comment: @zoli 1.So as to close the curve. 2.if you had to do only one rotation, you wouldn't have choice and you would go for a pi rads rotation to go back to the initial point. If you were to do more, it wouldnt be a triangle. 
The process I described does result in a triangle but you could go for a different process if you want to. 
PS : by rotation I mean instantaneous change of direction